# Javascript function falling out of Scope? "X is not a function" "X is a "" "

Tags: javascript

I have a JS function that is called on click that passes a string, and the first button works, however all subsequent buttons give me the error

```
action is not a function (In 'action("upvote")', 'action' is "")
```

Where action is the name of the function and upvote is the passed variable.

Using inspect element shows me the two buttons are identical, here is what they look like

```
<button type="button" onclick="action('upvote')">Like</button>
```

The weirdest thing is the button right before it calls a function as well and that work properly for all buttons not just the first one

```
<button type="button" onclick="fun(84)">Reply</button>
```

I checked and I am not forgetting to close any divs or buttons

The only thing I can think of is that I am echo these through a recursive php function, I don't think JS functions have scope, but I don't see why the first button work but not subsequent

Please let me know if more code is needed

The below code is my print function for the parent divs

```
 echo 
"<div class='parent' style='margin-left:".$width."px'>".$x['comment']."
    <div class='actions'>
       <button  type='button' onclick='fun($ran)'>Reply</button>
        <button type='button' onclick='action(\"upvote\")'>Like</button>
         <button type='button'>Dislike</button>";
    //Reply Like and Dislike are all actions every user gets, here I check which user it is to see if they can see the edit/delete
    //Normally I would check for admin rather than id == 2, but there is only 1 admin and he id 2
    if(($comment['userid'] == $_SESSION['id']) || $_SESSION['id'] == 2){
         echo "<button type='button'>Edit</button>
               <button type='button'>Delete</button>
</div>";//Close of actions div
      }
     else{
        echo"</div>";//Close of actions div
      }
    $uname = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = ".$comment['userid']." "));
    echo"
    <div class='info'>
    Score: ".$comment['score']." &nbsp; &nbsp; Posted By- ".$uname['username']."&nbsp; &nbsp At-".$x['created']." ";
    if($x['edited'] != NULL){
       echo"&nbsp; &nbsp; Edited Last-".$x['edited']." </div>";
    }
    else{
       echo"</div>"; 
   }?>
 </div> //Close of parent div
```

Here is still part of the function me checking if the comment has any reply comments and if so I recursively call the same function,

```
$check = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user_comment WHERE replyid = ".$x['id']." ");
if(!$check || mysqli_num_rows($check) == 0){
    return;
}
else{
    $working = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check);
    $new_reply = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id = ".$working['commentid']." "));
    print_comment($new_reply,$db,$width+20,$working);
}
```

Comment: Please, add more relevant code to your question. Thanks

Comment: I just added some more code, as for the action, it works properly with the first button but not subsequent, which is what confuses me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`action` in the inline event handler refers to the `action` property of the form containing the clicked element. It shadows your global `action` function, use a different name for the function, or rather use `addEventListener` to attach events. You can see the value in the snippet.

```js
function foo(a) {
  console.log(a);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button type="button" onclick="foo(action);">
    Click
  </button>
</form>
```

The reason behind this is, that the code in an inline handler is scoped to the event target element using `with (event.target) {...}` (or similar internal scoping mechanism), and when the given variable (property actually) is not found from the element itself, [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) looks up the ancestor elements until the property is found. If it's not found from the elements, the last object to search is `window`, and this way it finds the global function which was meant to be executed, providing there wasn't naming conflict on the way up to `window.`