# Second inputs onclick() function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

There were similar questions, but not exactly what I'm looking for. I have a filter for my table with 1 button that changes the value of a textbox to the currant date. That works fine, but right next to it, theres a button to clear the content in the textbox. This second button doesnt seem to work.

My code :

```js
function today() {

  var today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  today = yyyy + '.' + mm + '.' + dd;

  document.getElementById("myInput").value = today;
}

function clear() {

  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";
}
```

```html
<div class="form-inline">
  <label for="myInput">Filter By:</label>
  <input class="input-xsmall" type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="yyyy.mm.dd" id="myInput" style="width: 100px; margin-bottom: 10px; display: inline-block">
  <input type="button" value="Today" onclick="today()">
  <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clear()">

</div>
```

Not sure how to get it to work. When I switched the onclick function in the first input as `clear()` it worked so for some reason the second input button doesnt work. How can I fix that?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61664663/javascript-function-falling-out-of-scope-x-is-not-a-function-x-is-a/61665146#61665146)

Comment: @Teemu turns out I named it wrong. about the link you posted, is `(action)` an in built function? haven't seen a code of that sort before

Comment: No, `action` is not a function, it's the property reflecting the action attribute of a form. Similarly in your case, `clear` is a method of form elements, and it shadows your global `clear` function. I'm just wondering, why the clear method was never called, I would had expected it to clear the form ...

Comment: oh. thank you. i'll keep that in my mind if i need it in the future :)

Comment: Or if you don't have a form, it looks like Mahesvirus has linked to the correct answer explaining what is going on on your code.

Comment: yeah. i do have a form but its below this code so Mahesvirus's answer works well

Comment: Yep, the anwer to my question, why the method didn't do anything, is explained at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear) "_In recent versions of Mozilla-based applications, as well as in Internet Explorer and Netscape 4, [clear()] does nothing_"

Comment: right. thanks for that info as well :) was super confused because it didnt even throw an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the name of that `clear()` function. And also consider looking into [event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers).

Comment: this did the trick. thanks. I guess `clear()` was a reserved name or something of that sort?

Comment: thanks again man. that completely went over my head. I need to be more careful naming these lol. prob the second time now :/

Comment: No problem at all!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the js function name from clear() to something else. Because clear() is a javascript built in function/method. 
[Javascript Clear fields Function Not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108310/javascript-clear-fields-function-not-working)

Comment: thanks buddy. that part completely went over my head

Answer (score 1):

`clear` is not a reserved keyword. It is a scope problem

But still if you want to use same function name. can try below code.

Changing your existing function `onClick="clear()"` to `window.clear()` can fix your issue.

Refer this [Ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript)

```
<input type="button" value="clear" onclick="window.clear()">
```

Comment: wow i forgot about `windows.clear()` as well. thanks man! this does the job without additional JS

Answer (score 1):

Unlike what is written here, ***clear*** is not a word reserved in ***js***.

Here is the list of reserved words([from s3 site](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp))
[image: Here is the list of reserved words]

[Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7165861/9118235), why sometimes it acts as a reserved word

Comment: thanks. this should help me for some stuff in the future. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Or just add an event listener instead

```
document.querySelector("[type='button'][value='Clear']").addEventListener("click", clear);
```